# JSON object shows in dev tools but unable to access with dot notation

Tags: javascript, json

[image: Screen shot of Chrome dev tools]

I can't seem to access the JSON object. Tried dot notation.
Image is of Chrome dev tools.

`console.log(artwork_data.artItems)` comes up with undefined when I try to access properties, like `artwork_data.artItems.artId`.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You appear to have an array that **contains** an object. Access the array, and then access the object within.

Comment: You're trying to index an ARRAY using dot notation

Comment: `artwork_data[0].artId`

Comment: I am pushing to an object like this first. var artwork_data = {artItems:[]};

Comment: when I try artwork_data[0].artId getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'artId' of undefined

Comment: If you're just typing into the console without being paused at a breakpoint where `artwork_data` is in scope, that's going to be undefined. Otherwise the variable name isn't correct.

Comment: yeah @1252748 I think that is what's happening thx!

Answer (score -1):

In order to access that object you would need to first access the element within the array for example:

```
$.each(artwork_data, function (index, value) {
     console.log(value.artId);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You assumed the user is using JQuery. You should always assume no frameworks are present unless explicitly mentioned.